# Efficient way to extract a row and do cosine similarity

Tags: scala, apache-spark, svd

In the code below, I get a dense Matrix V after doing SVD. What I want is

1. Given a set of values(say 3,7,9).
2. I want to extract the 3,7 and 9th row of Matrix V.
3. I want to calculate cosine similarity of these 3 rows with each row of Matrix V
4. I need to add the three cosine similarities obtained for of each row.
5. I finally need the index of row which have the maximum summation.

> ```
> val data = Array(
>       Vectors.sparse(5, Seq((1, 1.0), (3, 7.0))),
>       Vectors.dense(2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0),
>       Vectors.dense(4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0))
>
> val dataRDD = sc.parallelize(data)
>
> val mat: RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(dataRDD)
>
> // Compute the top 4 singular values and corresponding singular vectors.
>
> val svd: SingularValueDecomposition[RowMatrix, Matrix] = mat.computeSVD(4, computeU = true)
>
> val U: RowMatrix = svd.U  // The U factor is a RowMatrix.
>
> val s: Vector = svd.s  // The singular values are stored in a local dense vector.
>
> val V: Matrix = svd.V  // The V factor is a local dense matrix.
> ```

Please advise an efficient method to do the same.  I have been thinking of converting Matrix V to Indexed Row Matrix, But when I do use row iterator on V, How do I keep track of index of rows? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681794/spark-scala-how-to-group-dataframe-rows-and-apply-complex-function-to-the-grou) can be a good help for you